# Summarizing a dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe which contains the voyages undertaken by different vessels over a period of time. A voyage typically consists of a single **commencing port**, single or multiple **loading port/s** and a single or multiple **discharging port/s**. My goal is to find the number of miles between commencing port to loading port, if there are multiple loading ports, then from one loading port to the next and also from loading port to discharging port. I also need to find the month in which a particular leg was undertaken. Here is some test data:

```
test <- structure(list(Vessel = c("STI Selatar", "STI Selatar", "STI Selatar", 
"STI Selatar", "STI Selatar", "STI Selatar", "STI Selatar", "STI Selatar", 
"STI Selatar", "STI Selatar", "STI Selatar", "STI Selatar", "STI Amber", 
"STI Amber", "STI Amber", "STI Amber", "STI Amber", "STI Amber", 
"STI Amber", "STI Amber", "STI Amber"), VoyNum = c(14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 
62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L), Port = c("ROTTERDAM", "ROTTERDAM", 
"ENGLISH CHANNEL", "GIBRALTAR", "PIRAEUS", "ELEUSIS", "ELEUSIS", 
"AGIOI THEODOROI", "SUEZ CANAL", "SINGAPORE STRAIT", "YOSU", 
"DAESAN", "BOTANY BAY", "NAPA NAPA", "NAPA NAPA", "PNGLNG TERMINAL", 
"TORRES STRAIT", "SINGAPORE STRAIT", "SINGAPORE", "SINGAPORE STRAIT", 
"TOLO HARBOUR"), Function = structure(c(2L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 
14L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 14L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 
4L), .Label = c("Canal Transit", "Commencing", "Delivery", "Discharging", 
"Fuelling", "Loading", "Other", "Passing", "Port Call Cancelled", 
"Redelivery", "Repair", "Sampling", "Terminating", "Waiting"), class = "factor"), 
    Date_Arrival = structure(c(978307200, 1535198400, 978307200, 
    978307200, 1537237440, 1537696800, 1537736460, 1538161920, 
    1539118440, 978307200, 1541531520, 1541736000, 978307200, 
    1520194320, 1520258460, 1520654400, 1520800560, 978307200, 
    1521556560, 978307200, 1522321200), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Date_Departure = structure(c(1535196600, 
    1536346080, 978307200, 978307200, 1537688160, 1537736340, 
    1538155080, 1538938800, 1539190800, 978307200, 1541621880, 
    1541979000, 1519702560, 1520258340, 1520642520, 1520740800, 
    1520837280, 978307200, 1521894960, 978307200, 1522461600), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), BallastLaden = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), Miles = c(4, 2930, 0, 0, 24, 0.43, 23, 623, 7466, 
    0, 338, 0, 1720, 0.43, 43, 213, 2594, 0, 1424, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The `Miles` variable shows the distance between the current row and the next row. `VoyNum` is the ID of the voyage undertaken by a vessel. The `Function` variable contains information on commencing loading and discharging. To find out which month the particular leg was undertaken, I am looking at finding the interval between `Date_Departure` and `Date_Arrival`, half it and add it to `Date_Departure`. This is the desired output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 7
  Vessel      VoyNum FromPort        ToPort          Miles BallastLaden Month
  <chr>        <int> <chr>           <chr>           <dbl>        <int> <chr>
1 STI Selatar     14 ROTTERDAM       ELEUSIS         2958.            0 Sep  
2 STI Selatar     14 ELEUSIS         AGIOI THEODOROI   23             1 Sep  
3 STI Selatar     14 AGIOI THEODOROI YOSU            8089             1 Oct  
4 STI Selatar     14 YOSU            DAESAN           338             1 Nov  
5 STI Amber       62 BOTANY BAY      NAPA NAPA       1720.            0 Mar  
6 STI Amber       62 NAPA NAPA       PNGLNG TERMINAL   43             1 Mar  
7 STI Amber       62 PNGLNG TERMINAL SINGAPORE       2807             1 Mar  
8 STI Amber       62 SINGAPORE       TOLO HARBOUR    1424             1 Mar
```

How can I use `dplyr` to achieve this as a combination of `group_by()` and `summarize()`?

I can summarize the total ballast or laden miles like this, but then this is not what I really need as each of these legs are further broken into multiple ports:

```
test %>% group_by(Vessel, VoyNum) %>% summarise(BMiles=sum(test$Miles[BallastLaden==0]),                                                      LMiles=sum(test$Miles[BallastLaden==1]))
```

Comment: please revise your question. Only show input, desired output and what you have tried and detele unhelpful text.

Comment: @Jimbou thanks, edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(lubridate)
test %>% group_by(VoyNum) %>% arrange(Date_Departure) %>% mutate(cumMiles = cumsum(Miles)) %>%
  filter(Function %in% c("Commencing", "Loading", "Discharging")) %>% 
  mutate(Miles = c(diff(cumMiles - Miles), last(Miles)), ToPort = lead(Port),
         Month = month(Date_Departure + floor(c(Date_Arrival[-1], 0) - Date_Departure) / 2, label = TRUE)) %>%
  rename(FromPort = Port) %>% slice(-n()) %>%
  select(Vessel, VoyNum, FromPort, ToPort, Miles, BallastLaden, Month)
# A tibble: 8 x 7
# Groups:   VoyNum [2]
#   Vessel      VoyNum FromPort        ToPort          Miles BallastLaden Month
#   <chr>        <int> <chr>           <chr>           <dbl>        <int> <ord>
# 1 STI Selatar     14 ROTTERDAM       ELEUSIS         2958.            0 Sep  
# 2 STI Selatar     14 ELEUSIS         AGIOI THEODOROI   23             1 Sep  
# 3 STI Selatar     14 AGIOI THEODOROI YOSU            8089             1 Oct  
# 4 STI Selatar     14 YOSU            DAESAN           338             1 Nov  
# 5 STI Amber       62 BOTANY BAY      NAPA NAPA       1720.            0 Mar  
# 6 STI Amber       62 NAPA NAPA       PNGLNG TERMINAL   43             1 Mar  
# 7 STI Amber       62 PNGLNG TERMINAL SINGAPORE       2807             1 Mar  
# 8 STI Amber       62 SINGAPORE       TOLO HARBOUR    1424             1 Mar
```

Comment: truly brilliant! Thank you so much for this!